# Are there "higher-n" versions of a binomial distribution?

Tags: distributions

Are there "higher-n" versions of a binomial distribution? Like trinomial, quadrinomial, etc?

Specifically, I am interested in the likelihood of how incoming events stack up. I have 4 "bins" of type A, and one "bin" of type B. Each incoming item is sorted into a bin with a given likelihood. (2/9 for each A and 1/9 for B, if it matters). I am interested in finding a formula describing likelihood of different distributions of items. E.g, if three items come in, what is the likelihood that three will end up in one A, vs. 2 and 1, vs. 1 and 1 and 1. I can solve low numbers by thinking hard, but I'm not sure how to generate a distribution for 10+ items.

One more wrinkle: I'm looking at this as a potential simplification of part of a larger stochastic model. As such, "there is no trivial answer" is useful to me even if there is a complex or unsolved solution.

Comment: @Sycorax That looks like exactly what I was asking about! Unfortunately, it also looks hard to apply. I need to think about this for a while.

Comment: The multinomial is not particularly hard to use to work out the probability of a specific event (like with "5 observations with these probabilities $p_i$ of an observation appearing in bin $i$, what's the probability of getting three in bin 1, one in bin 2, none in bin 3 and one in bin 4?" -- that's easy to do); the particulars of your case could simplify things a bit as well. Can you more clearly give a specific calculation you need to perform?

Comment: @Glen_b it's schoolwork, so I'm more looking for aproach than solution. But after simplifying, I have what is essentially an ornate queuing problem: (1) a batch of events comes in at the top. (2) a random process removes most events from the queue (3) any events remaining are sorted randomly into "buckets" (4) each bucket randomly removes additional events (5) each remaining event has a probability of causing event X. What is the likelihood of at least one event X? Steps 3-5 are independent of each other and of 1 and 2. 1 and 2 *might* be independent of each other.

Comment: @Glen_b I have reduced steps 4+5 to a single probability of X occurring as a function of number of events in that bucket, but 2 in one bucket != 1 in each of two buckets. I'd like to generalize to a probability of X as a function of n events coming out of (2), and I think the way to do that is to take the sum across all the possible end-states of (3) of the likelihood of ending in that state times the likelihood of that state causing X.

Comment: @Glen_b (also, the "schoolwork" part is modelling the whole thing. I'm exploring this as a potential simplification and because I think it's interesting. It's generally in scope, but is neither necessary nor sufficient by itself)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The multinomial distribution generalizes the Bernoulli distribution to $k$ categories and $n$ trials. The [Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) is unusually good.

The multinomial distribution has PMF
$$
\frac{n!}{x_1!\cdots x_k!}p_1^{x_1}\cdots p_k^{x_k}
$$
which should intuitively "look" like a binomial PMF for $k=2$. (Note that
$\sum_ip_i=1$ and $\sum_ix_i=n$.)
I don't know what software you're using, but it is [implemented in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Multinom.html), which might remove some of the tedium from your project.

Comment: This Wikipedia summary got me started on a couple of assignments in grad school. Agreed that it's excellent!